# I get an error "Failed building wheel for regex" when trying to build sa-logic app using docker

Tags: python, regex, docker, gcc, pip

I am new to docker and ubuntu. Trying to build containerized Sentiment Analyzer application as documented in Renor's article:

- [Learn Kubernetes in Under 3 Hours: A Detailed Guide to Orchestrating Containers](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-kubernetes-in-under-3-hours-a-detailed-guide-to-orchestrating-containers-114ff420e882/).
- source code can be found at: [github.com/rinormaloku/k8s-mastery](https://github.com/rinormaloku/k8s-mastery)

I was able to successfully build sa-frontend and sa-webapp, however when I am trying to build sa-logic using the below command it fails with the following error:

```
...
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/regex_3/_regex.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
...
```

[image: screenshot]

I am using Python version 3.8.3, pip: 20.1.1

Comment: Your screenshot contains the answer to your question. It says very clearly what the problem is: "unable to execute 'gcc': no such file or directory". You do not have C compiler installed, and this Python package have parts in C code. If you're using Ubuntu, `apt install build-essential` will install everything you need.

Comment: Yes I already ensured build-essential is installed.
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).

Comment: Well, your screenshot does show that gcc is not installed. Do you run this inside docker container? Did you install `build-essential` *inside* that container?

Comment: your screenshot says otherwise.

Comment: gcc is installed, gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 I am not running inside the docker container. I have a python logic app that I am trying to build a container image and then push it to a self hosted container registry. So I am trying to do this on Ubuntu 18.04 OS. The github repo is available here github.com/rinormaloku/k8s-mastery

Comment: What surprises me is, when I check the pip version it says 20.1.1 the error in the screenshot says "You're using pip version 18.1 however 20.2 is available. When I try to upgrade using " pip install --upgrade pip" it says already up to date

Comment: Welcome to SO @JayanthYK. For your future questions try to include everything needed to recreate the problem :-). You can read more about this here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, it's better to post error messages with text and not screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `gcc` seems to be missing from the base image used (`python:3.6.6-alpine`) at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/rinormaloku/k8s-mastery/blob/master/sa-logic/Dockerfile) provided by this tutorial. If you change it to `python:3.6-slim` it seems to build successfully:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
COPY sa /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
    python3 -m textblob.download_corpora
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["sentiment_analysis.py"]
```

Comment: You're bang on. 3.6-slim in the Dockerfile fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! I really don't know if you can accept the answer now that the question has been closed, but if you can... please do so that it doesn't list as an "unanswered" one.